# Exporting highchart to server w/ phantomjs & highcharts-convert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, phantomjs

I´m trying to export a chart server side using phantomJs. After googling around for articles and examples of this using rails I found this api:

https://github.com/kbaum/highchart-image-api

which can be pretty much summed up by saying that is using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and [highcharts-convert.js](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs)...and calling some rails code on the server.

Now, the problem relies on the beginning. After including all the resources in the [latest link](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs) an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error comes up on line 36 of highcharts-convert.js and I can't seem to get out of this mess.

help?

PS: I added phantomjs with [this](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem) gem

Comment: Maybe the problem is within that gem? According to readme from "highcharts-image-api", installation should be done via `brew`: `gem install brew`, `brew install phantomjs`

Comment: I'm beginning to think that higcharts-convert and phantomjs is only ment to use server side so I think I really don't need it on the frontend. But still tests to be made...

Comment: You are right, you don't need phantomJS and highcharts-convert if you want to use them on frontend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

highcharts-convert should not be added in the frontend, it is meant to be used only on the server side by phantomjs